# como limpar um atributo em html pelo javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

estou com um problema no meu código onde ele pegar um valor do banco relacionado ao valor do combobox selecionado pelo usuario e preenche em outro combobox, até ai esta funcionando porém quando o usuário da um onchange novamente ele acrescenta os valores em vez de sobreescrever tentei usar a função reset() e clear() do jquery não funcionou segue o codigo abaixo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").change(function() {
        var valor = $("#button").val();
        alert(valor);
        $.post("procura.php",
            {valor: valor},
                function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    var resultado = data.split(",");
                    for ( var i = 0 ; i < resultado.length ; i++ ){
                        var option = $("<option></option>").appendTo($('#result'));
                        option.attr("value", resultado);
                        option.html(resultado[i]);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("form").reset();
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="button">
    <option value="AVT">AVT</option>
    <option value="MMFT">MMFT</option>
    <option value="RUNIN">RUNIN</option>
</select>
<select id="result" name="result">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: você me dá a liberdade de editar o título da sua pergunta para que ela faça mais sentido? "Como remover as options de um select antes de atualizá-lo com outras,via Javascript"

Answer (score 0):

Amigo tenta resetar os options do seu select antes do novo preenchimento:

```
$("#button").change(function () {
        var valor = $("#button").val();
        alert(valor);
        $.post("procura.php",
            { valor: valor },
            function (data) {
                alert(data);
                var resultado = data.split(",");
                $('#result').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
                    var option = $("<option></option>").appendTo($('#result'));
                    option.attr("value", resultado);
                    option.html(resultado[i]);
                }
            });
    });
```

Desse modo sempre que vier algum valor novo do banco de dados, ele limpa o seu combobox e adiciona os valores novamente.
Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você limpar o select com id="result".

```
 $("#result").empty();
 //Aqui segue seu código
 var option = $("<option></option>").appendTo($('#result'));
```